# R Summarization already summarized on Pipelines

Tags: r, sum, pipeline, summary, summarize

I'm extracting information from a database summarizing it and writing it on an Excel file.

This information is practically the value of variable totyta summed up when uppv3 is equal to a value, and it has 9 different values.

I calculated all 9 values with this pipeline successfully and wrote it into Excel for each calculation, 9 times.

```
data_fbh %>% select(uppv3,ar_bygg,agkat,far1,totyta) %>%
  filter(uppv3==1) %>%
  summarise(tot = sum(totyta)) %>% paste()%>%
  as.numeric() %>%
  round(0) %>%
  writeWorksheetToFile(file = "rapport.xlsx", data = ., sheet = "T2.4",
                       startRow = c(9), startCol = c(27), header=F)
```

Now, I don't need the totals of each 9 sum, but the percentage of each along all the 9 totals.

I already have the values on the table, but I'm not able to make the percentage, because I already summarize the table and the other information is not anymore (other uppv3 values).

Any idea of how to accomplish this still using pipelines?

[image: Table XLS with values but not percentages]